# Custom dateTimepicker never updates value

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Iam using a custom `dateTimePicker` but whenever i change value in UI , it takes the value stored in its property tab .

```
 dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm";
        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Properties : [image]

Date i set during Runtime : [image]

i showed the date using `MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString())` value shown :  [image]

Comment: When you say `custom dateTimePicker`, is that one you wrote, did you get it as a library from a colleague, is it a 3rd Party control? If it is one you didn't write, perhaps you need to consult the creator of the control first before asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: `dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm";` it's a .NET4.5 library , with customized format

Comment: yes i did , but alaways the same problem : sometimes days change but months stay as they were ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your format is incorrect: `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm`. Try `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm`

Comment: Dude , I spent hours on this shit . you saved me a lot more hours .. Thnks

Comment: The uppercase `M` is for Month while the lowercase `m` is for minute or millisecond.